# apps assigned to a desktop space are different with and without monitors (mac)

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors, desktop

I use spaces on my mac, and I assign applications to specific spaces (e.g., Word to Desktop #5). I use keyboard shortcuts to "Switch to" a specific desktop, so I effectively have a keyboard shortcut to an application. There are other ways of doing this, but I like this implementation.

I have two monitors. The left monitor I assign Desktops 1-4, and the right monitor I assign Desktops 5-9.

The problem is that when I'm using my monitors, Word will open on Desktop #6, instead of Desktop #5 like it's assigned (without monitors). So my keyboard shortcuts are effectively different with or without monitors. When I right-click the app in the dock, it shows "Desktop on Display 2" so I'm not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

**Some questions received:**

**1. Basis for assignments:**

**What's the mechanism for associating desktops with monitors ("permanent" settings somewhere that get triggered by attaching the monitors, a real-time manual procedure, a script you run when plugging in the monitors)?**

**A**: To associate a desktop to a monitor, activate Mission Control and along the top of the screen slide a desktop from one monitor to another monitor (as long as you are not currently on the desktop you want to move)

**What's the mechanism for assigning windows/tasks to desktops (permanent settings, manual procedure, script)?
If assignments are based on settings, what happens when desktop assignments mysteriously change (do the actual assignments conflict, or do the settings get changed and the assignments are then consistent with them)?**

**A**: To assign an app to a specific desktop: Without the monitors connected to the laptop, go to a specific desktop, right-click the app in the dock and Options > Assign to > "This Desktop"

**2. Effect of monitor connections:
What happens if you attach only one of the monitors, and does it make a difference which one?**

**A**: If I disconnect either monitor, all spaces are assigned to the monitor that is plugged in (as if using the laptop only) and Desktop opens in the correct space (Desktop #5).

**How is each monitor connected (type of port and graphics card)?**

**A**: HDMI ports on the macbook (or HDMI to thunderbolt connection). I have a 2012 Macbook Pro - so there are two thunderbolt ports on the left-hand side and an HDMI port on the right-hand side. I connect Monitor #1 (as defined by the menu bar placement in arrangement settings in System settings app) to the thunderbolt port next to the USB (via monitor>HDMI>thunderbolt dongle) and leave the thunderbolt port next to the charger connection open; Monitor #2 is connected directly to the HDMI port on the right-hand side of my macbook.

**3. Assignment of desktops to monitors:
Is the change in desktop assignment always associated with desktops on the same one particular monitor?**

**A**: Yes, apps open in correct spaces on Monitor #1 (as defined by the menu bar in arrangement system settings) but not on Monitor #2. This behavior doesn't change if I switch ports or move the menu bar in arrangement preferences in system settings app.

**What happens if you change your allocation of desktops to monitors (random new assignment, different quantity of desktops per monitor)?**

**A**: When both monitors are plugged in, if I move Desktop #5 to Monitor #1, Word still opens in Desktop #6 on the second monitor. However, if I keep Desktop #5 on Monitor #1, unplug both monitors, assign Word to Desktop #2 (or any random desktop), reassign Word to Desktop #5, plug back in both monitors (Desktop #5 remains on Monitor #1), and open Word, Word will open in the correct desktop (Desktop #5, which is on Monitor #1).

**Assuming some assignments still change, is it the same desktop numbers that change, regardless of which monitor they're now on, or is it whatever desktops are now in the same sequence relative to the desktop list on the "problem" monitor, or something else?**

**A**: Given my response to the previous question, and my experience in general, it seems to only affect desktops on Monitor #2.

**4. Assignment of windows to desktops:**

**Do you have exactly the number of desktops you need, or extra desktops, some of which are available if needed?**

**A**: I have one or two desktops that do not have assigned apps, I some times go to these desktops to view apps that are not assigned to a specific desktop, or allowed on all desktops (eg Finder app), so that I can view them in a less cluttered space. The behavior does not change if I delete these unnecessary desktops (FYI these are desktops #8-9 on Monitor #2).

**Do you always assign just one window/task to a desktop or do some desktops normally have multiple windows?**

**A**: All windows for an app will open on a given desktop. I sometimes move a window to the other monitor (eg when viewing a PDF and its copy to see different parts of the PDF at the same time). Some desktops have multiple apps assigned to them, some do not.

**When the assignments mysteriously change, does the number of windows in any desktop change (e.g., application gets bumped to a new desktop, then shares that desktop with another application that was previously there)?**

**A**: No.

**5. Nature of the pattern:**

**You mention certain windows moving to a higher number desktop. Does:
a collection of desktops shift, leaving an unused desktop that previous had something assigned to it, or 
do you end up with a missing desktop, or
does a new desktop with new content get inserted, bumping all higher number desktops?**

**A**: The 'bumping up' (app opening in the next highest desktop #) only happens when initially opening the app (eg apps open in the next highest desktop# for desktops on Monitor #2), new windows will open on whichever desktop the app opens on. So the answer to the ", or does a new" question is No. And I do not end up with missing desktops, at least from what I've observed using the monitors for over a year or so.

**If the latter, what application is that?
Imagine this as a phantom desktop being inserted somewhere and bumping other desktops. Does the location of that insertion suggest anything diagnostic (e.g., replacing last desktop on 1st monitor, which bumps one to the 2nd monitor and affects all the rest on the 2nd; or inserted as 1st desktop on 2nd monitor, bumping others on 2nd monitor)?**

**A**: Whatever is goin on, it seems to be associated with Monitor #2, which only refers to whichever monitor does not have the menu bar assigned via arrangment settings in the System settings app.

**After the changes, do you have the same total number of desktops or more desktops? Does count of desktops on each monitor match the intended count (regardless of which ones they are)?**

**A**: I always see the same number of desktops that I have on the laptop without monitors. When the monitors are plugged in, I see these same desktops, but they are associated with the monitor that I last associated them with (Normally desktop#1-4 are on Monitor #1, and desktops5-9 are on Monitor#2, but if I move a desktop from one monitor to another then unplug both monitors and plug them back in then the computer remembers where I had the desktops last).

Comment: I don't understand the "with and without monitors " bit at all. Are you changing the screen configuration, disconnecting one... what? Is this a laptop with 2 extra monitors, or a desktop, or an iMac with a separate monitor..?

Comment: What Tetsujin said.  But also, what do you gain by assigning groups of desktops to specific monitors?  Why not just use whatever desktop you want at the time on either monitor.  It seems like that would give you more flexibility and functionality.

Comment: @Tetsujin - This is a laptop with two external monitors. When using my laptop (without monitors) apps open in the correct space (eg Word opens in Desktop #5). When using my monitors (with monitors) Word opens in Desktop #6. So my keboard shortcut to the desktop (the shortcut I use to go to Word) changes when I'm using my laptop (without monitors = command+5) and when I use monitors (with monitors = command+6 to get to the desktop with Word).

Comment: @fixer1234 - Because I have apps assigned to spaces/desktops, it's useful to have one monitor be more or less fixed (eg my left monitor I have a web browser, which I use with jupyter notebooks), and my right monitor be the one that changes more often (I have iTerm, Word, etc on that monitor). Another reason why I assign desktops to monitors is that I can know which monitor to expect to change when I use a keyboard shortcut to go to a specific desktop - I look at my right monitor when I want to go to the desktop with Word, or Papers, or iTerm.

Comment: "This is a laptop with two external monitors." ... or as we say in the trade, I have three monitors...

Comment: @Tetsujin helpful comment! My laptop is in clamshell mode and is therefore not a monitor.

Comment: 1. Only monitor1 plugged in.  You open Word and it opens in D5.  You then plug in monitor2.  The desktop with Word moves to monitor2.  Is it then labeled as D5 or D6?  2. Both monitors connected, all 9 empty desktops on their assigned monitors.  Are M2 desktops all correctly labeled (5-9)?  You display all 5 D's as a grid (#5=top left, #6=top middle,..).  You start opening the apps that are assigned to the M2 desktops.  Do just certain apps end up in the wrong desktop or all of them?  One of them is Word.  It opens in D6.  (cont'd)

Comment: In the grid array, is that the first desktop (top left)  but it is now labeled 6 instead of 5, or does Word open in the top middle desktop?  3. Word is assigned to D5.  Same setup as previous example, with 5 empty D's on M2.  You manually open some app in D6, then open Word.  Does word end up with the other app in D6?